# Get checkbox values using checkbox name using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have several input checkboxes, (they name is same for send array on server).

So, I need get each value this checkboxes and I want use as selector checkbox names, this not works, help please.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="bla[]" value="2" />
</form>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready( function () {    

   $("input[name=bla]").each( function () {
       alert( $(this).val() );
   });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sZGjr/)

Comment: Your code will work, if you remove [] in name param means bla[] to bla

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You are selecting inputs with name attribute of `"bla"`, but your inputs have `"bla[]"` name attribute.

```
$("input[name='bla[]']").each(function (index, obj) {
        // loop all checked items
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26axX/

Comment: Thanks very much, thanks everybody, I will accept this answer :)

Comment: Add :checked to find only selected checkboxes as $("input[name='bla[]'] :checked").each( function () {

Answer (score 20):

If you like to get a list of all values of checked checkboxes (e.g. to send them as a list in one AJAX call to the server), you could get that list with:

```
var list = $("input[name='bla[]']:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 14):

You should include the brackets as well . . .

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bla[]" value="1" />
```

therefore referencing it should be as be `name='bla[]'`

```
$(document).ready( function () { 

   $("input[name='bla[]']").each( function () {
       alert( $(this).val() );
   });

});
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$('[name="CheckboxName"]:checked').each(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add that if you're trying to get all of the check-boxes with that name that have been selected, you would want to use the following syntax:

```
$("[name='bla[]']:checked").each(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Make sure there is not a space between the closing `]` and `:checked`

Comment: Good to see using `:checked` selector and avoiding an extra `if statement`

Answer (score 6):

// get checkbox values using checkbox's name

```
<head>
        <script>
        function getCheckBoxValues(){
            $('[name="checkname"]').each( function (){
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkname" value='1'/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkname" value='2'/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkname" value='3'/>
        <input type="button" value="CheckBoxValues" onclick="getCheckBoxValues()"/>
    </body>
```

// get only the values witch are checked

```
function getCheckBoxValues(){
        $('[name="checkname"]').each( function (){
            if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("input[name='bla[]']").each( function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Like it has been said few times, you need to change your selector to

```
$("input[name='bla[]']")
```

But I want to add, you **have** to use single or double quotes when using [] in selector.